# Search functionality to search for particular chart among multiple charts in dashboard

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, jsp, highcharts

I am making a spring application with java and JSP. In the Dashboard, I am showing multiple stockcharts using Highstock chart. Now I have a search bar above the charts and I want to search for a particular chart.

I have tried using Js but unsuccessful so please help me with this and suggest me approaches.

Comment: search bar is searching the chart based on data it holds or type of chart name ?

Comment: I am showing the charts for different agricultural products so I want to search by product name but I haven't used that product name in the chart

Comment: As search functionality is based on product name and its independent of chart as such. There are different ways you can do it but one simple method can be, add product name as meta data in the json data which you bind to the chart and maintain object of product name to charts  container ids and that way you know which product is present in which chart. check the search value in the product to charts object list and display only those chart containers which holds them and hide rest.

Comment: Can you provide an example for this? As I am new to highcharts and JS so it is difficult for me to implement.

Comment: check below the representative code

Answer (score 0):

All Highcharts charts are stored in the globally defined Highcharts.charts array which you can filter to find the wanted chart (for example by their container id).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w29pL0zg/

```
console.log(Highcharts.charts)
```

Check the console.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below code in browser. use productId1, productId2 or productId3 for searching.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

  //create productid to chart containerid mappings (on server side itself)
  const searchList = {
    productId1: ["container11", "container13"],
    productId2: ["container12", "container1"],
    productId3: ["container2", "container3", "container13"]
  }

  // create list of all the chart container ids (on server side itself)
  const chartList = ["container1","container2", "container3", "container11","container12","container13"];

  // search function for searching productid (exact match)
  function searchProduct() {
    // take the user input value for the productid
    const searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchBox").value;
    console.log(searchTerm);

    //get the list of all chart containerid list for productid user has searched 
    const chartListForProduct = searchList[searchTerm];

    // hide all charts when user is searching
      chartList.forEach((containerId) => {
        const chartContainer = document.getElementById(containerId)
        chartContainer.style.display = "none"
      });

    // mappings are available for given searched product id display only those charts
    if(chartListForProduct){
      chartListForProduct.forEach((containerId) => {
        const chartContainer = document.getElementById(containerId)
        chartContainer.style.display = "block"
      });
    } 
  } 

</script>

</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <h1>
    Search chart by productId
    </h1>
    <input type="text" id="searchBox" value="" />
    <button name="search" onClick="searchProduct()"> Search</button>
  </div>

  <br/><br/><br/>

  <div id="container11">Chart 11....</div>
  <div id="container12">Chart 12....</div>
  <div id="container13">Chart 13....</div>
  <div id="container1">Chart 1....</div>
  <div id="container2">Chart 2....</div>
  <div id="container3">Chart 3....</div>


</body>
</html>
```